# Can we add Twitter permissions on demand in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, twitter, authentication, permissions

We are making an iOS app that has two points of integration with Twitter:
1. User can use Twitter account to login (or FB account or just email/password)
2. User can share his freshly done work to twitter (just post a tweet)

So for some users we need a read/write access to twitter, but for some only minimal permission for loggin in would be enough and I wouldn't like to scare users away by asking for a write permission on the first login, when they might not even realize the app can share their work to Twitter.

Is it somehow possible to request only login permissions on first start and tweeting permission only on a first Tweeting need?

P.S.
We are not going to use the built-in iOS sharing sheets, because they are good only for sharing to *either* FB OR Twitter OR elsewhere. We want to offer sharing to Twitter, Facebook, Email and maybe somewhere else simultaneously, in a foursquare app style

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the recent changes, but I believe that the permission is the one you set in https://dev.twitter.com/apps. So no, you can't do it. I don't think you can do that on facebook as well.

(sidebar: twitter's documentation now is complete mess. I can't find any useful information there)

Comment: For Facebook it is not only possible, Facebook nowadays actually recommends requesting permissions in the granular way for pretty much the same reason of not scaring the user away with the posting permission request, when he just wants to login to have a look.
    
Quote from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/ : "Best Practice: apps should request permissions in context to improve the user experience and the conversion rate for the request. For example, the sample app only requests `publish_actions` the first time the user posts a checkin."

Comment: Interesting,.. I'd still play _Draw Something_ had they did it that way after being purchased by Zynga.